# Having difficulty OHS rewrite rule for multiple domains

Tags: mod-rewrite, oracle-http-server

I'm having a bit of difficulty with rewriting on Oracle HTTP Server for multiple domains that point to same IP address and port

Following is working

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub-doamin-1/psp/UACMP/SELF_SERVICE/SA/c/NUI_FRAMEWORK.PT_LANDINGPAGE.GBL [R,L]
```

However when I try https://sub-doamin-2/analytic it redirects to the https://sub-doamin-1/psp/UACMP/SELF_SERVICE/SA/c/NUI_FRAMEWORK.PT_LANDINGPAGE.GBL

Tried RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} method with no luck. It just redirect to / (root)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} sub-doamin-1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub-doamin-1/psp/UACMP/SELF_SERVICE/SA/c/NUI_FRAMEWORK.PT_LANDINGPAGE.GBL [R,L]

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} sub-doamin-2$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub-doamin-2/analytics
```

Can you please assists resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `${HTTP_HOST}`

So the rules should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub1.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub1.test.com/psp/UACMP/SELF_SERVICE/SA/c/NUI_FRAMEWORK.PT_LANDINGPAGE.GBL [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub2.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub2.test.com/analytics [L]
```

You can check the rules here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=6632e45c-a7bb-5099-ab0b-468ba1066277

for the urls https://sub1.test.com and https://sub2.test.com

If you write your original rules in that website you will get `This test string is not supported: ${HTTP_HOST}` so this can also help you next time.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. I must pay attention to syntax much closer next time. Your help is much appreciated.